# how do you count players' wins, losses and draws from a series of tictactoe(x and o) replays?

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements, counting

I have a file containing tictactoe(x and o) replays. Only two players play in each game. A player plays more than once, so he could win more than once, or loose more than once. He could also draw more than once. How do I track such a player? And there are more of them in the game.

I'm using a dictionary to track every game; player as key and status(win = True, loose = False, draw = None) as values. All dictionaries are in 1 big list.

example: [{'Ash': None, 'Gary': None}, {'Misty': True, 'Brock': False},...]
what's the best way to track them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may store all the players in one dictionary:

```
player_stats = {'Ash': {'win': 1, 'loose': 0, 'draw': 0},
                'Gary': {'win':1, 'loose': 2, 'draw': 3},
                ...}
```

you have to make sure that all the players have a unique name, or add an alias

Comment: Good point. I have stored the players in a similar dictionary format. It helps keep track of who had what in a game.

Comment: thx, answer was helpful. To accept answer, does one need to click or like a button around here?